# Solr / Lucene token n-gram: leading and trailing stopwords removal only

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there a way to remove just the leading and trailing stopwords from a token n-gram?

Currently I have the following combination which removes any n-gram that contains a stopword:

```
<analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="3"
                    outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" tokenSeparator=" "/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern=".*_.*" replacement=""/>
</analyzer>
```

For example, if my document contains these ngrams:

"Tower of London", "Tower in London", "and London", "London",

with "of, in" as stopwords, the shingle filter will produce:

tower _ london, tower _ london, _ london, london

(note that however the second "tower _ london" is different from the first but this bit of information is lost)

and the pattern filter will then delete the first 3 n-grams.

What I really want to do though is to keep "tower of london", "tower in london", "london", "london".

Is this possible?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you are concerned about that loss of information, why remove stopwords at all?  Seems to me that common stopwords don't really have less impact at the begining or end of a sentence than they do in the middle.  After all "in the way" and "on the way" have significantly different meaning as well.  Why not just remove the `StopFilterFactory` from your analyzer entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out [CommonGrams](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#CommonGramsFilterFactory) analyzers instead of Shingle ones. I don't think they are a perfect match (they only do bigrams), but you may find they perform more closely in search to what you want.

The other option is to stick a [PatternReplace](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#PatternReplaceFilterFactory) filter factory in the chain after the Shingle and to catch those common words at the start of the n-grams and replace them away. You may also need [RemoveDuplicate](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory) filter after that to only keep one version of - now identical - tokens.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I tried to build an autocomplete functionality that would derive suggestions from shingled tokens (trailing stopwords would look funny).

I ended up developing a TokenFilter that does exactly that: https://github.com/spyk/shingle-stop-filter. You can check it out if you don't mind adding an extra jar to Solr. Also, it only works for trailing stopwords for now, although it could be adjusted for leading ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but it worked for me and I thought it would be interesting to other people that may face the same issue.

The order you put the filters in fieldType interfere in the result.
When using ShingleFilterFactory before the StopFilterFactory I obtained exactly the result you are expecting.

```
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(^[^a-zA-Z0-9á-úÁ-Ú]*|[^a-zA-Z0-9á-úÁ-Ú]*$)" replacement=""/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" outputUnigrams="true" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="6"
        tokenSeparator=" "/> 
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_pt.txt" />
    </analyzer>
```